# Google OpenId - redirect_uri/callback not happening. Is the issue localhost?

Tags: node.js, networking, google-api, google-oauth, google-openid

Following the the [Google OpenID doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect), I am attempting to send an authentication request to Google.

When the request goes out to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth, the request is not redirected back to my redirect_uri http://localhost:5901. I also am not getting the google login screen(not sure if I am supposed to get a login screen).

I checked the CLIENT_ID and it is correct.

Is the issue here localhost?

[image]

```js
const URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';

// initial login; redirect to get permissions
const constructCodeURI = () => {
  const queryString =
    `client_id=${CLIENT_ID}`
    + `&scope=openidemail`
    + '&state=019146662993491234567890'
    + '&login_hint=foo.bar@gmail.com'
    + '&nonce=03852-31485-24958'
    + `&redirect_uri=http://${HOST}/auth/google/callback`
    + '&response_type=code';

  return `${URL}?${queryString}`;
};

// user gives permissions and you get user code
const redirectToGoogleLogin = (req, res) => {
  const url = constructCodeURI();
  console.log('aaa');
  console.log(url);
  res.redirect(url);
};  


const callbackStack = (req, res) => {
  console.log('This is not being hit');
  if (Object.keys(req.query).length > 0) {
    getTokenAndProfileStack(req, res, code, 'google')
      .then(e => res.redirect('http://localhost:5000/forms/ui/list_forms'))
      .catch(e => console.log('google login call back err ' + e))
  }
};

export default callbackStack;
```

```
// google login
app.route('/auth/google/login')
  .get(redirectToGoogleLogin);

app.route('/auth/google/callback')
  .get(callbackStack);
```

Request that goes out (modified to remove sensitive info)

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=20oogleusercontent.com&scope=openidemail&state=034912340&login_hint=foo.bar@gmail.com&nonce=02-31905-8&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:5901/auth/google/callback&response_type=code
```

Comment: I believe you need space in between your scope, i.e. `openid%20email`. One way to debug is you copy the url generated from `constructCodeURI` and paste it in your browser

Comment: Please try using ${HOST} = 'localhost:5901' instead of '127.0.0.1:5901'

Comment: Are you getting any error in you console, if so can you please share the log?

Comment: Have you checked the request in the network panel of your browser's developer tools? Maybe there's some useful info there. (e.g. a server error)

Answer (score 1):

Answering from my own experience:

1. Add `http://localhost` (without a port) to the authorized redirect URIs list while keeping the other options you have setup.
2. Within `constructCodeURI` make sure to replace `127.0.0.1` with `localhost`.